# Horizontal scroll bar on welcome page only

Tags: responsive-design

I tried body {overflow: hidden} trick but it hides everything below "View Details and Buy" button. Checked the elements through Inspector and none seem to overflow. I can't exactly point out the issue. Same template is used for other pages and those are working fine.

Getting the scroll bar on this page:
http://www.satyatunes.com/web/index.php

The same template is used on this but it's working fine:
http://www.satyatunes.com/web/store.php

The welcome page is not responsive on mobile/ipads also.

Comment: Where do you see a scroll bar? Because i don't see anything. (Chrome 32-bit).

Comment: It's browser's horizontal scroll bar. I see it in Chrome, FF and IE8.

Comment: I'm not seeing the horizontal scrollbar in Chrome FF or IE8. EDIT: Or Safari.